# Azure Server returns 500 status without thrown error

Tags: c#, angular, azure, .net-7.0, azureportal

I have some issue with an application deployed on Azure.

On my local deployment when I do something that throw new exception (for example I tried to add new user with same UserName like other user) server return status 500 and in `F12 -> Console -> Network -> Request -> Preview`
I get an exception message like this: "System.Exception: Exception message (...)"

[image: screenshot from localhost request]

When I tried to recreate the error in Azure, I receive only status 500 without any data in `F12 -> Console -> Network -> Request -> Preview`

[image: screenshot from azure request]

I need to have that data from the request error because, I create errorHandler with messages for user, and it don't work without request error message.

Application is written in C#/.NET 7.0 and Angular 15+

Comment: I assume you are using the Azure app service? Would this be useful? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#stream-logs

Comment: @Mateusz Wąsik please share the code

Comment: @Sampath I'm not sure what part of code you need so I paste link to

GitHub repo: https://github.com/MateuszWasik1/Organiser-BackEnd

Comment: Do you have `Web.config` in your Deployed root folder?Cross check once.

Comment: do try to check the appinsight if its configured -Especially Trace .Saying because in my case ,we missed a data that made the circular dependency .